# Malformed bcf file not recreated by latexmk after error

Tags: biber, latexmk

I'm using `latexmk` with `pdflatex` to compile my thesis, with `biblatex` for references and `biber` as backend. It compiles fine and creates correct PDF output. If a change to the source files introduces an error the first run of `pdflatex` fails but a bcf file is created. The run of biber then complains about a malformed bcf file indicating that the last `biblatex` run failed and the compilation is stopped. However, after fixing the error `latexmk` thinks the `pdflatex` run was fine and invokes `biber`, but the bcf file is still malformed.
`latexmk` somehow doesn't seem to notice that there were file changes.

Removing the bcf file or cleaning it with `latexmk -C` makes `latexmk` call `pdflatex` first and recreate a correct bcf file. Calling `pdflatex` manually also work but defeats the purpose of `latexmk`. I tried to use `-halt-on-error` as option to `pdflatex` but that doesn't work. I seem to recall that it worked with TexLive 2014, after a failed attempt to run `biber` `latexmk` would run `pdflatex` first on the next attempt.

I'm using TexLive 2015, the version of `latexmk` is 4.43a, `biber` has the version 2.3. The output produced is

```
Latexmk: This is Latexmk, John Collins, 5 February 2015, version: 4.43a.
Rule 'biber thesis': File changes, etc:
   Non-existent destination files:
      'thesis.bbl'
------------
Run number 1 of rule 'biber thesis'
------------
------------
Running 'biber  "thesis"'
------------
Latexmk: applying rule 'biber thesis'...
INFO - This is Biber 2.3
INFO - Logfile is 'thesis.blg'
ERROR - thesis.bcf is malformed, last biblatex run probably failed. Deleted thesis.bbl
INFO - ERRORS: 1
Latexmk: Failed to find one or more biber source files:
  NONE
Collected error summary (may duplicate other messages):
  biber thesis: Could not find all biber source files for 'thesis'
Latexmk: Use the -f option to force complete processing,
 unless error was exceeding maximum runs of latex/pdflatex.
Biber error: [33] Utils.pm:163> ERROR - thesis.bcf is malformed, last   biblatex run probably failed. Deleted thesis.bbl
Latexmk: Errors, so I did not complete making targets
```

Obligatory mwe.tex:

```
\documentclass[paper=a4]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\addbibresource{Bibliography.bib}

\begin{document}
\autocite{smith_pixel_1995}
\end{document}
```

Bibliography.bib

```
@article{smith_pixel_1995,
    title = {A Pixel Is Not A Little Square, A Pixel Is Not A Little Square, A Pixel Is Not A Little Square!},
    volume = {6},
    url = {http://ftp.alvyray.com/Memos/CG/Microsoft/6_pixel.pdf},
    journaltitle = {Microsoft Computer Graphics, Technical Memo},
    author = {Smith, Alvy Ray},
    urldate = {2016-02-04},
    date = {1995}
}
```

Steps to reproduce:

1. run `latexmk -pdf mwe`
2. introduce an error in `mwe.tex` like an undefined control sequence
3. run `latexmk -pdf mwe`
4. when prompted abort compilation with by pressing `x`
5. fix error
6. run `latexmk -pdf mwe` -> biber error
7. run `latexmk -pdf mwe` -> same biber error, won't go away

So the question is, how do I get `latexmk` to re-create the bcf file so that biber can use it without having to manually clean or remove files?

Comment: I don't use latexmk, but doesn't the option -f as mentioned in your log ("Latexmk: Use the -f option to force complete processing,") work? Or run simply once pdflatex instead of latexmk.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Yes, -f works. But as I see it, the point of `latexmk` is not to have to reprocess everything from scratch; as a quick workaround it's still a solution.

Comment: Actually I can't reproduce your problem. If I change the tex-file, e.g. add an x, and then start latexmk it always calls pdflatex first and so also repairs a broken bcf.

Comment: That's what I feared. Just to be sure, you are using the same version of latexmk as I?

Comment: You can just re-run `latexmk` after the failed Biber run without doing anything else and everything will work fine - provided you have fixed the problem in the TeX file and it compiles without errors. See the discussion in [issue #348 at the `biblatex` bugtracker](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/348). (I think the `latexmk` developer is also active here, so he might drop by and give some more info.)

Comment: @moewe Thanks, I didn't consider to look for `biblatex` bugs. From what I gather from the comments in the bugreport the endless `biber` error loop affects not only me and is not fixed yet. For now, I'll thinks it's easiest to simply invoke `latexmk` with the `-gg` switch and recompile everything from scratch.

Comment: I don't think this is a bug *per se*. It is not that easy to decide what the intended behaviour ought to be (other than, make it work of course). I believe `-gg` is a bit of an overkill, just run latexmk again if the compilation stops with the `.bcf` malformed error. This places a tiny bit more responsibility on you, but it doesn't force latexmk to redo everything from scratch.

Comment: Sorry to comment again, but I just realised you said something about an "infinite loop". That is not something I ever got, a second run always worked fine (provided the problem was solved, of course). Can you reproduce (or give a recipe to reproduce) the infinite loop?

Comment: @moewe I added some more steps, the biber error always happens. The behavior I observe is the same dbitouze describes in his [comment](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/348#issuecomment-155856870) in the discussion of the issue you linked. My `biber` and `latexmk` versions match, the `biblatex` version probably too. That is the bug I was referring to; the circular dependency John Collins describes, that is difficult to resolve correctly, I accept.

Comment: I have the same problem. If you fix the error in the tex, `latexmk` will still run biber first which aborts due to crippled `bcf`. Least trouble for me is removing the crippled file.

Comment: Mhhh, when I do the same, in step 7 I get a smooth compilation starting with pdfLaTeX and not the error from step 6.

Comment: @moewe It happens for me since I switched to the current `biber` version (2.3), with 1.8 and `latexmk` from TexLive 2014 on the second try `pdflatex` was run.

Comment: You get the warning `Latexmk: Use the -f option to force complete processing, unless error was exceeding maximum runs of latex/pdflatex.` I don't think that more than this can be done on the `latexmk` side.

Comment: Yes, I gather that is because the handling of malformed `.bcf`s was changed with Biber version 2.2/2.3 (or therabouts) and between latexmk 4.39 and 4.43a. I have Biber 2.3, `biblatex` 3.2, latexmk 4.43a. I mght be doing something horribly wrong (or rather right), but I still struggle to reproduce step 7 in your recipe above.

Comment: I'm putting some code in `latexmk` to fix this.  Meanwhile, one work around is to delete the offending `.bcf` file by hand.  (Note that how problem shows itself depends on the exact versions of both `latexmk` and `biber`.)

Comment: I've put a corrected version (4.44) of `latexmk` at http://users.phys.psu.edu/~collins/latexmk/  It should fix the problems described in the question, and I plan to submit this to CTAN shortly.  But it would be useful for some regular users of `biber` to test the updated version to ensure the fix doesn't cause some other problem.  (I am not a regular user of `biber`, so I have only tested the new version on very simple examples.)

Comment: @JohnCollins Thanks for the support. I gave 4.44 a quick test with the MWE and my thesis and it looks pretty good so far. `latexmk` is detecting that `biber`  failed due to a malformed `bcf` file and is running `pdflatex` instead. Just as I expected. Again, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As already mentioned in a comment, the solution is to use the new version of `latexmk` (4.44 at the time I write this answer), which is now available at http://www.ctan.org/pkg/latexmk/

Answer (score 1):

Update <del>May 2019</del> March 2020:

This is still an issue with 18.04 LTS of Ubuntu (bionic), because they deliver version [4.41](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/latexmk).

As stated by [John](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/295992/189284) this is fixed since version 4.44. Newer versions of latexmk are delivered for cosmic, disco, eoan, focal,..

There are at least three ways to upgrade, choose one of them:

a) Download and install the `.deb` package manually, e.g. from https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/all/latexmk/download and hopefully it does not require any further dependencies to be upgraded.

b) I fixed that issue on my machine, by temporarily use the cosmic repository:

1. edit /etc/apt/sources.list at line of universe repo from bionic to cosmic, save
2. apt update
3. apt install latexmk
4. revert changes in /etc/apt/sources.list
5. apt update

Both is in general not recommended, but latexmk is a very simple app/script with few dependencies. Pinning is not required because hopefully the maintainer won't choose a version between 4.41 and 4.44, current version in cosmic is 4.59.

c) Another approach would be loading the newest package from [CTAN](http://ctan.org/pkg/latexmk/) and install it like in the documentation, basically replace and adjust permissions. See [How can I upgrade latexmk / why very old version is contained in Ubuntu repository?](https://askubuntu.com/a/883925/45131).

Comment: Just download the `.deb` file from https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/all/latexmk/download and install it manually. No need to mess with the system sources.