# The bbl file is not generated and still malformed file bcf even if I still use \addbibresource{file.bib} in XeLaTeX

Tags: biblatex, xetex, abnt

I have already tried by middle of the following questions:

- [Problem with biber: file.bcf is malformed](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/363934/problem-with-biber-file-bcf-is-malformed)
- [Bbl file not generated](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/354196/bbl-file-not-generated)
- [Malformed bcf file not recreated by latexmk after error](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/294813/malformed-bcf-file-not-recreated-by-latexmk-after-error)
- [biber generate empty bbl file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/378495/biber-generate-empty-bbl-file)

I use:

- Manjaro Linux
- XeTeX 3.14
- Biber 2.12
- Class abnetx2
- Package biblatex-abnt

The version of `bibtex`: `BibTeX 0.99d (TeX Live 2018/Arch Linux)`

I ran like:

```
xelatex -synctex=1 -halt-on-error --shell-escape artigo.tex
biber artigo.tex
```

I also tried to run `biber referencias`.

It did not generate the bbl file.

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[11pt, article, a4paper, oneside, sumario=tradicional, chapter=TITLE, section=TITLE, subsection=Title, subsubsection=title, subsubsubsection=title, english, german, greek, portuguese]{abntex2}

\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[backend = biber, dateabbrev = false, giveninits, ittitles, justify, language = brazil, sorting = none, style = abnt, url = true]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{referencias.bib}

\begin{filecontents}{referencias.bib}
@article{antonioleitao,
    Address = {Campinas},
    author = {Antonio Leitão},
    date = {1996-10-08},
    Publisher = {UNICAMP},
    title = {Funções Recursivas},
    url = {http://www.dca.fee.unicamp.br/courses/EA072/lisp9596/node17.html},
    urldate = {2018-11-03}
}
\end{filecontents}


\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{brazil}
\frenchspacing 
\maketitle
\begin{resumoumacoluna}
 \vspace{\onelineskip}
   Blablabla
 \noindent
 \textbf{Palavras-chave}:
\end{resumoumacoluna}

\renewcommand{\resumoname}{Abstract}
\begin{resumoumacoluna}
 \begin{otherlanguage*}{english}
   \vspace{\onelineskip}
      Blablabla
   \noindent
   \textbf{Keywords}: 
 \end{otherlanguage*}  
\end{resumoumacoluna}

  \printbibliography

\end{document}
```

The xetex error log:

```
\myptabbox=\box87
\myptabboxwidth=\skip292
Package biblatex Info: XeTeX detected.
(biblatex)             Assuming input encoding 'utf8'.
Package biblatex Info: Automatic encoding selection.
(biblatex)             Assuming data encoding 'utf8'.
\openout4 = `artigo.bcf'.

Package biblatex Info: Trying to load bibliographic data...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'artigo.bbl' not found.
No file artigo.bbl.
Package biblatex Info: Reference section=0 on input line 380.
Package biblatex Info: Reference segment=0 on input line 380.
Package lastpage Info: Please have a look at the pageslts package at
(lastpage)             https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pageslts
(lastpage)             ! on input line 380.
```

The biblatex error log:

```
[0] Config.pm:304> INFO - This is Biber 2.12
[1] Config.pm:307> INFO - Logfile is 'artigo.blg'
[39] biber:315> INFO - === Wed Dec 12, 2018, 18:22:11
[61] Utils.pm:209> ERROR - artigo.bcf is malformed, last biblatex run probably failed. Deleted artigo.bbl
[62] Biber.pm:114> INFO - ERRORS: 1
```

I also have checked:

```
biber --cache
No cache - you are not running the PAR::Packer executable version of biber
```

Comment: The example as shown will not produce any output, because it does not contain any citations. If I add `\cite{antonioleitao}` to the example and compile with XeLaTeX, Biber, XeLaTeX, XeLaTeX I get the expected output. `biber artigo.tex` is the wrong call, it must be `biber artigo` without file extension (of if you insist on extensions `biber artigo.bcf`). I do *not* get the Info about `lastpage` in my log file. Is the `.log` you have shown us from the code example? Delete all temporary files and try again. If it still does not work, please upload the `.bcf` file to https://pastebin.com/

Comment: Then I ran without tex extensions and it was still the same error. Here is the pastebin link: https://pastebin.com/ShSZPg9q

Comment: That `.bcf` is malformed: it is missing important parts. This should not happen. Is that the `.bcf` you get from the *exact* MWE you posted? Please verify that in a new, empty directory. Please upload the complete `.log` file of the first XeLaTeX run on your file in the empty directory.

Comment: Bizarrely, it worked without problems on Overleaf. Yes, it was. Here is the pastebin link of XeLaTeX error log: https://pastebin.com/ZrKP6DES

Comment: The `.log` does not come from the code you have shown us in the question. The `.log` shows that you load `csqoutes`, but the MWE does not load it (there are a few more packages like this). Please *always* make sure that the code you show and the `.log` files are about the same thing. Anyway, the `.log` clearly mentions an error: `./artigo.tex:384: Undefined control sequence. <recently read> \theforeigntitle`. This error aborts compilation and leaves the `.bcf` in an unfinished state. Fix this error (and all other errors that occur and try again).

Comment: Ah, I got, here is the BibLaTeX error log and LaTeX error log od MWE code: https://pastebin.com/bMnasZQB and https://pastebin.com/8VtbNykd. Is it still the same error of \theforeigntitle?. As from the line 384, I will update the MWE.

Comment: In the future, please make sure that the code you post as working example in the question produces the output you think it does and actually reproduces the issue. Please test this in a new, empt directory to avoid any kind of interference. It is extremely frustrating if we get to see code as a minimal example, but on request you provide us with log files for a different (more complicated) document. It becomes really difficult to help you in that case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The posted `.log` file (which does *not* come from the MWE as shown in the question) shows a fatal error towards the end

```
./artigo.tex:384: Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \theforeigntitle

l.384
```

if such a fatal error aborts the TeX run it is possible that the `.bcf` file is not written out completely and hence corrupted. In that case Biber can't read the file properly and complains

```
[61] Utils.pm:209> ERROR - artigo.bcf is malformed, last biblatex run probably failed. Deleted artigo.bbl
```

The only way to get going again is by fixing all errors that you encounter when you compile your TeX file. This is always advised anyway, not only when you run Biber: Errors must be fixed, the output is not guaranteed to be valid if LaTeX encounters an error. **Never ignore error messages.**

Apparently the `abntex2` class requires you to give the author, title and English title of the work in `\autor`, `\titulo` and `\tituloestrangeiro`, respectively if you want to print a title with `\maketitle`. Otherwise errors are thrown.

```
\documentclass[11pt, article, a4paper, oneside, sumario=tradicional, chapter=TITLE, section=TITLE, subsection=Title, subsubsection=title, subsubsubsection=title, english, german, greek, portuguese]{abntex2}

\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[backend = biber, style = abnt]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{brazil}
\titulo{Brazilian Title}
\tituloestrangeiro{English Title}
\autor{Gustavo}
\maketitle

\cite{sigfridsson}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

works and produces

[image: Title page, an example citation and the bibliography]

Comment: But my professor asked me not to include the foreign title due to the college's ABNT rules

Comment: @GustavoReis Sorry, that's all I can say. The class will throw an error if no title is given. And errors like this *must* be addressed. You can of course say `\tituloestrangeiro{}` or you can have a look at the documentation (which is in Portuguese, which I don't read) to see if there is a way to turn the foreign title off.

Comment: I added `\tituloestrangeiro{}`(with empty title), and it worked.

Comment: I still want to know who on earth uses those rules for "articles", but anyways...